# MySQL returns wierd result with normal query

Tags: php, mysqli

So I have this code:

```
    <?php
    $main = new Main;
    $conn = $main->db_connect();
    $module = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM modules");
    $modulelist = $module->execute();
    $modulelist = mysqli_fetch_array($module->get_result());
    var_dump($modulelist);
```

And it returns this instead of the normal values in the table:

> array(12) {
>
> [0]=>   int(2)   ["ID"]=>   int(2)   [1](https://i.gyazo.com/260f13140d80eb03edbe6ff8501a6b2c.png)=>   string(7)
> "anderes"   ["Naam"]=>   string(7) "anderes"   [2]=>   string(4)
> "0.00"   ["Beschrijving"]=>   string(4) "0.00"   [3]=>
> string(4) "0.00"   ["Prijs"]=>   string(4) "0.00"   [4]=>
> string(0) ""   ["Prijsweergave"]=>   string(0) ""   [5]=>
> int(2)   ["Termijn"]=>   int(2) }

This is the table:[image: Table]

Comment: Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` then you get only an Assoc array and not the numeric one as well

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-array-parameters) has an explanation. Whenever you get results different from what you expect, your first order of business should always be consulting official documentation to see if maybe you overlooked, misunderstood or assumed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your issue is that the way you have written your code, you only ever get One result printed from a multiple result query.

The `$module->get_result()` can only be called once as it gets the whole resultset the first time, so the second call will return nothing.

```
$module = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM modules");
$modulelist = $module->execute();
$results = $module->get_result();
while ( $row = $results->fetch_assoc() ){
    var_dump($row);
}
```